# Export pdf file into text file using PDFCreactiveX class

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-conversion

I am in strange problem while exporting pdf file into text file using PDFCreactiveX class which is found under Interop.ACPDFCREACTIVEX.dll dll. The problem varies by system wise. When I export in my pc then only one line shifted to top and when I export it into another pc then one more line is shifted to top.

The process of exporting pdf to text file is as follows.

--> Create PDF document using RDLC report.
--> Convert that PDF into text file using PDFCreativeX class.

I am using following code to export PDF to text file.

```
StringBuilder pdfTextData = new StringBuilder();
        pdfFileName = String.Format(@"{0}\{1}", USPSAPI.appDataWorkingPath, pdfFileName);
        PDFCreactiveX pdfCreater = new PDFCreactiveX();
        pdfCreater.SetLicenseKey(Constants.COMPANY_NAME, Constants.AMYUNI_LICENSE_KEY);

        if (File.Exists(pdfFileName))
        {
            pdfCreater.Open(pdfFileName, "");
            pdfCreater.Refresh();
            pdfCreater.ExportToRTF(pdfFileName.Replace(".PDF", ".U.TXT"), acRtfExportOptions.acRtfExportOptionText, 1);
        }
```

If you need any other clarification then let me know.
Thanks,
Awadhendra

Comment: For the record, you are actually using the library Amyuni PDF Creator ActiveX. I would advise you to contact Amyuni Support at support@amyuni.com. Make sure that you provide this sample project, your licensing information, the exact version of the library that you are using (example: 5.0.1.3), the PDF file that you are having issues with, and a detailed description of the problem. Disclaimer: I work for Amyuni Technologies.